# how to return data when task is completed

Tags: c#, .net

I start some task like this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

void SomeMethod()
{

}
```

Is there is a way to return data when task is completed?

like

```
List<User> SomeMethod()
{
  List<User> = List<User>();
   ...
   return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes like this.
By using the generic overload of `Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)` your task defines a return type. Then with `task.Result` you can access your result.

```
Task<List<User>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<User>>(SomeMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

RunSomeOtherMethod();         // We can do other work in parallel...

List<User> result = task.Result;  // Wait for task to finish and fetch result.
```

---

```
List<User> SomeMethod()
{
  List<User> = List<User>();
   ...
   return userList;
}
```

---

If you would like to pass one or more parameters to your function use a lambda to start your function:

```
Task<List<User>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<User>>(
    () => SomeMethod("inputString"), //Starting the method using a lambda so you can pass in a parameter.
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
);

RunSomeOtherMethod();         // We can do other work in parallel...

List<User> result = task.Result;  // Wait for task to finish and fetch result.
```

---

```
List<User> SomeMethod(string input)
{
  List<User> = List<User>();
   ...
   return userList;
}
```

For more information about threading and Task Parallelism I would like to refer you to the online ebook: [Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism)

Comment: When I use SomeMethod(string "someString) I am facing some exception. Could u suggest please if there is any special syntax for it?

Comment: @Peretz I added another example so you can pass in parameters to the method.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `Task<TResult>` instead of `Task`.

```
List<User> SomeMethod()
{
  List<User> = List<User>();
   ...
   return userList;
}

var task = Task<List<User>>.Factory.StartNew(SomeMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

then you can get result by calling task.Result

Also, you can use continuation task which will by invoked after result will by available.

Answer (score 2):

In C# v7, the syntax offered by Hamlet Hakobyan and SynerCoder isn't strictly necessary because the return value of .StartNew() is automatically inferred based on the SomeMethod argument.

```
List<User> SomeMethod()
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    return userList;
}
async Task DoWork()
{
    List<User> users = await Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```